# How do I control indentation of wrapped lines in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, indentation, visual-studio-2019

I have Visual Studio 2019 (Community at home; Professional in the office). I also have ReSharper. I set up line length to be 120; indentation at 4, and autoformatting on close brace or semicolon. The language is C#

The problem is that indentation of the wrapped line is completely unpredictable (at least to me). Sometimes it is indented 4 characters as I expect; sometimes it is under a parenthesis or to the right of `=>` or same operator (like `&&`). So, frequently wrapped line starts at character 80 or 90!

How can I make it *always* indent 4 characters from the previous line?

Needless to say that I tried a dozen of combinations of options under Visual Studio and Resharper Code Editing - Formatting options. Visual studio doesn't seem to have *any* option that would make it push the new line. Resharper has Parenthesis section under C# - Formatting style. But nothing makes wrapping simple

Example:

```
lstGroup.Select(s => new Group
{
    ...
    Status = lookup.Where(w => w.LookupType == LookupConstants.CRIMETYPE &&
        (int?)w.LookupIndex == (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.TempCrimeType) ? 0
        : Convert.ToInt32(s.TempCrimeType))).Select(w => w.LookupDescription).FirstOrDefault(),
    ...
});
```

(it may not be clear, but the lines don't run past char; so I would like it to stay this way!). After hitting semicolon at the end of the statement, it turns into

```
Status = lookup.Where(w => w.LookupType == LookupConstants.CRIMETYPE &&
    (int?) w.LookupIndex == (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.TempCrimeType)
        ? 0
        : Convert.ToInt32(s.TempCrimeType))).Select(w => w.LookupDescription).FirstOrDefault(),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can completely simplify indents for wrapped statements/expressions, but the following options should make it much easier. If something still irritates you, please amend your question with examples.

**Tabs, Indents, Alignment**

- Set all options in "Parenthesis" section to "Parenthesis and inside equally"
- Turn off all options in "Align Multiline Constructs"

**Brace Layout**

- Set "Expressions (initializers, switch expressions)" to "At next line indented (Whitesmiths style)"
- Consider also to whether you want to also change "Lambda and delegate" to the same style

UPDATE: To prevent ReSharper from re-wrapping your code, go to "Line breaks and wrapping" page and look for options called "Wrap ..." with values "Chop if long or multiline" and "Chop always". Change them to "Simple wrap" as needed. You may also want to ensure that all "Keep existing arrangement..." options are turned on. Your particular example is influenced by a setting called "Wrap ternary expression".

Comment: Thank you. I added an example, where VS reformats, and it's just terrible...

Comment: Actually, on the second thought, the indentation of the wrapped lines is much better. I put an example where I would prefer not to wrap *at all*!

Comment: Actually, I can live with these options. and wrapping is probably a different question. Let me mark it as accepted; but if you have some thoughts about wrapping (or link to Resharper docs - couldn't find anything relevant) - thank you in advance!

Comment: @Felix Updated answer

Comment: Ouch - I completely missed that section! Бальшое спасибо :D